# adding get parameters to wordpress page link

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress I want  to add the Get parameters for some pages

currently my paramlink settings are are to `example.com/pagename/`

what I want do is `example.com/pagename?a=1&b=2`  add these two parameters only in `pagename` page

I tried to do like this in my .htacess

`RewriteRule ^pagename/([^/]+)$  pagename?a=1&b=2`

But this is not working

is there any way I can do it in my wordpress website
I am using wordpress 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Use `add_query_arg` functionalities to do this, for ref - [code doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/)

Comment: add_query_arg( 
    array( 
        'a' => '1',
        'b' => '3'
    ), 
    'example.com/pagename/'
);
Like this it is not working

Comment: where you actually linked your page just replace the link with add_query_arg like - add_query_arg(array( 'a' => '1', 'b' => '3' ), site_url('/pagename/'))